# Seagate HDD failure: is it a controller board issue?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

Wednesday, there were some issues with regards to my Seagate 3 TB HDD as it was having trouble reading the device.  Windows had popped up a "reboot your computer to fix drive issues", which I did.  It took a while for the drive to load up in which I attributed to the checking of the disk.  I thought nothing of it until the next morning when the drive disappeared from Windows, and any other attempt to load it up would cause the machine to hang.  SeaTools says that there is definitely a problem, and any attempt to do a long scan fails as it says it is unable to communicate with the drive.  I did attempt to try to do a partition clone to a new drive but the whole device failed before it would complete.  Now it won't start up at all, and my computer is having trouble resolving it when it boots up.

The reason I ask if it is a controller board issue is that if it is, and not due to a head or sector issue, then perhaps the controller board can be replaced, that is if I can find the appropriate part to replace it with.  Either way, it just means that the data on that drive is still intact and recoverable, but there may need to be some expertise involved.

Has anyone had this kind of failure before?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried replacing controller boards and I've done research on it in the past, don't ask me to reference it, but I can tell you with almost certainty it is not possible to replace the controller board and have a functional drive. The firmware on the board and the mechanics are paired up by the manufacturer and some type of low level reprogramming has to take place for it to work. You can't swap them and expect it to work. Seagates are notorious for shutting down whenever they hit a bad sector during cloning. So it's probably a physical problem compounded by electronics.

Comment: Quick reference I found: http://www.databe.com/articles/article4.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Someone pointed this out to me: http://www.hddzone.com/faqs.html

In my case, the HDD has SMART errors which the site says replacing a PCB will not help.

Answer (score 1):

If i can interject... The other day , within a 3 day time span , both a 2TB and 3TB Seagate Baracuda drives failed with the same issues. The 2TB kept disconnecting from the machine while trying to map the surface. While I was able to get the data off intact , I was curious as to why both had failed within days of each other.

A few facts , both drives are the same age , and have been running the same time in a Freenas based setup.

I removed the 2Tb logic board , and to my suprises found that the spring-loaded connectors that mate to the logic board , and the pads on the logic board had oxidized. It was easy to clean with a glass pencil for pcb work. Being curious , I checked the 3TB board , and found the same. I cleaned and reasembled both boards ( being careful not to swap them ) and placed the 2TB back for test... it passed without showing any of the past failures.

I have yet to run a full test on the 3TB drive...

Perhaps this can help somebody.
YMMV